# python requests | как отловить ошибку таймаута?

Tags: python, requests

вот есть запрос

```
import requests

try:
  res = requests.head(some_url, timeout=2.5)
  print(res)

except <тут должна быть ошибка, которая выпадет только из-за таймаута>:
  print('not responding')
```

какую ошибку мне туда написать, `requests.ConnectionError` не пойдет, вдруг там в корс ошибка будет или denied какой нибудь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка `Timeout` отлавливается `requests.exceptions.Timeout`

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions

Для примера нашел тяжелый сайт

```
import requests

try:
    res = requests.head('https://adventskalender.ifaw.de/', timeout=2.5)
    print(res)

except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    print('not responding')

--------------------------------

not responding
```